# Value from CMakeCache.txt not used consistently during makefile generation

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to set up a cross compilation environment for the Raspberry Pi Zero on Ubuntu 16.04 following the instructions here https://github.com/HesselM/rpicross_notes

There is a variable, RPI_ROOTFS, in the toolchain file that specifies where to find the copy of the Raspberry PI filesystem. The value from the original instructions is /home/pi/rootfs. I didn't want to hard-code values from my environment so I change

```
set( RPI_ROOTFS /home/pi/rpi/rootfs )
```

to this

```
set( RPI_ROOTFS "/home/pi/rootfs" CACHE FILEPATH "Raspberry Pi filesystem root")
```

I then used the following command to configure CMake to build the Raspberry PI userland

```
cmake \
  -D CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/rpizero-gcc \
  -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rpicross_notes/rpi-generic-toolchain.cmake \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -D RPI_ROOTFS=/home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs \
  /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/src/userland
```

However, when generating the build files I see a failure at this stage: Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_fac33/fast"

Looking in CMakeCache.txt I can see that the value for RPI_ROOTFs has been set correctly:

```
RPI_ROOTFS:FILEPATH=/home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs
```

But looking in CMakeError.log I can see the following.

```
/usr/local/bin/rpizero-gcc    -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include  -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include  -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include     -Wl,-rpath /home/pi/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath /home/pi/rpi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf  CMakeFiles/cmTC_fac33.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_fac33 -rdynamic 
rpizero-gcc: error: /home/pi/rpi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf: No such file or directory
rpizero-gcc: error: /home/pi/rpi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:     No such file or directory
CMakeFiles/cmTC_fac33.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target     'cmTC_fac33' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_fac33] Error 1
```

It looks like the value for RPI_ROOTFS from the cache has been used in some places and the default value in others

For example this value from the toolchain file looks to have used the cache version of RPI_ROOTFS

```
# setup RPI include/lib/pkgconfig directories for compiler/pkgconfig
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf")
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/include")
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/local/include")
```

Whereas this seems to have used the default

```
set( RPI_LIBRARY_DIR "${RPI_LIBRARY_DIR} -Wl,-rpath ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf")
set( RPI_LIBRARY_DIR "${RPI_LIBRARY_DIR} -Wl,-rpath ${RPI_ROOTFS}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf")
```

This second set of configuration is immediately after the first so I can't see what would could different values to be used

If I hardcode the value of RPI_ROOTFS for my environment (/home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/rootfs) in the toolchain file then everthing works

What could cause this?

For reference, here is the complete toolchain file:

```
set( RPI_ROOTFS "/home/pi/rpi/rootfs" CACHE FILEPATH "Raspberry Pi    filesystem root")
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${RPI_ROOTFS} )

# compilers
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER   "/usr/local/bin/rpizero-gcc"    CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/rpizero-g++"    CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( CMAKE_AR           "/usr/local/bin/rpizero-ar"     CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( CMAKE_RANLIB       "/usr/local/bin/rpizero-ranlib" CACHE FILEPATH "")

# Platform
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1 )
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE arm-linux-gnueabihf )
set( FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "hf" )
add_definitions( "-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -marm" )

# setup RPI include/lib/pkgconfig directories for compiler/pkgconfig
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem     ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf")
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/include")
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/local/include")

set( RPI_LIBRARY_DIR "${RPI_LIBRARY_DIR} -Wl,-rpath ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf")
set( RPI_LIBRARY_DIR "${RPI_LIBRARY_DIR} -Wl,-rpath ${RPI_ROOTFS}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf")

set( RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}:${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig" )
set( RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}:${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/share/pkgconfig" )
set( RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}:${RPI_ROOTFS}/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig" )
set( RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}:/home/dsnowdon/rpi-cross/ros/src_cross/devel_isolated" )

# C/CXX flags
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS        "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS          "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${RPI_LIBRARY_DIR}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

# Pkg-config settings
set( PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/pkg-config" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_DIR}         "" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR}      "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} "${RPI_ROOTFS}" CACHE FILEPATH "")

# Python2.7
set( PYTHON_EXECUTABLE          "/usr/bin/python2.7" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG       "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE     "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON_LIBRARY             "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR         "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/include/python2.7" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH      "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" CACHE STRING "")

# Boost
set( BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/" CACHE STRING "")

# OpenCV
set( OpenCV_DIR       "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/share/OpenCV/" CACHE STRING "")

# Userland / VideoCore
set( USERLAND_DIR     "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/src/userland" CACHE STRING "")
```

Comment: In short, when check a compiler, `cmake` is called again with the same toolchain ... but without command-line arguments. So during this check `RPI_ROOTFS` has value given in the script, not the one in the command line. It is better to use environment variable for customize toolchain. Or set environment variable in the toolchain itself, as shown in the answer to the referenced question.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev